# Sublime text editor installation problem in ubuntu

Tags: sublime-text

```
E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Kindly help me how to resolve this?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the broken APT repository using Software & Updates (`software-properies-gtk`) first. Then fix [it by](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html):

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Or install SublimeText using one of the methods below:

- [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.sublimetext.three)

  ```
  sudo apt install flatpak
  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
  flatpak install flathub com.sublimetext.three
  ```
- [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make

  umake ide sublime-text
  ```